# Given $f_{n}(x)=\frac{1}{1+nx}$, show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow ∞}f_{n}(x)=f(x)$ for every $x\in \left [ 0,1 \right ]$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity

For each $n\in \mathbb{N}$ consider the funcion $f_{n}:\left [ 0,1 \right ]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $f_{n}(x)=\frac{1}{1+nx}$. Define: 
\begin{align}
f(x)=\begin{cases}
1& \text{ if }\ x=0\\ 
0& \text{ if }\ 0<x\leq 1
\end{cases}
\end{align}

1. Show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow ∞}f_{n}(x)=f(x)$ for every $x\in \left [ 0,1 \right ]$
2. Prove that the following sequence $(f_{n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is not convergent in $C(\left [ 0,1 \right ],\mathbb{R})$ with the metric $d_{∞}$

Comment: Which metric is $d_{\infty}$? Is it $d(x,y) = | x- y |$?

Comment: @Olba12 It's the $\sup$ norm on $C([0,1], \Bbb R)$, the space of continuous functions from $[0,1]$ to $\Bbb R$, defined by $d_\infty(f, g) = \sup_{x \in [0,1]}\{|f(x)-g(x)|\}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

For 2) you should use the fact that if $f_n$ converges uniformly then $f$ must be continuous since $f_n$ are continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: (for 1) If $x = 0$ then $f_n(0) = ?$ and so $f_n(0) \to$? If $0 < x \leq 1$ then $1+nx \to$? as $n \to \infty$